# Conda new environment not showing package attribute

Tags: python-3.x, conda

Recently I created a new environment using Conda and then in the Jupiter notebook after enabling the new environment when I do the following

import pandas as pd

and after that, if I want to access attributes of pd using (. + tab) then it is not working for me.

I am not sure what I missing. This is happening for all the packages installed in this env.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: Where are you typing your code? Auto complete should be a feature of your IDE / Editor / Interactive Environment and not related to `conda`

Comment: In the Jupiter notebook after enabling the new environment.